# net.Interfaces() w/ bonding details

Tags: go

I'm trying to determine whether an interface is a slave to a bond or not, however, it appears the Go net interface() struct does not return this information even in the flags that I'm aware of.

Does anyone know how to determine this information?

Comment: https://godoc.org/github.com/vishvananda/netlink#BondSlaveState
Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: Go doesn't expose low-level networking stuff in the standard library. You can't configure an interface either, for instance. As Marco suggested, you have to find a netlink library (for Linux, anyway; no clue about other operating systems). I've had success with the mentioned package too.

Comment: Cheers guys. I will look into this.